How does an autotransformer change voltage if primary and secondary share the same wire?
I just learned what an autotransformer does, but I'm not understanding how it works.
So, a typical transformer has a primary wire wound around a magnetic core with an AC source, which creates an alternating magnetic field. The secondary wire is isolated from the primary wire but wound around the same magnetic core and relies on the alternating magnetic field to induce an AC output with the same power but different voltage and current.
I always (mis)understood the voltage and amperage change to rely on the fact the primary and secondary wires are not connected and the change is caused by how the magnetic field interacts with different amounts of wire wound around the core.
With an autotransformer, the secondary wire is connected to the primary wire. Why wouldn't the secondary wire just have the same voltage and current as the primary wire then? Why wouldn't every single wire (in my house, for example) with some twists and turns near magnetic materials be an autotransformer?

there are two wires connected to the secondary, not just one wire ... a circuit requires two wires

Here, for example (image from here) is a step-up autotransformer:

There are more turns around the magnetic core between the high side of the source and the output load (on top of the primary winding) so the voltage is higher. Ideally, the voltage out is Vsource \$\cdot\$ (N2/N1+1)
You can think of it something like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The voltage from the transformer adds (or subtracts, depending on the phase) from the source voltage. This is actually a useful configuration because you can use a small low voltage transformer to make a small adjustment to the mains voltage. For example, if you have 120VAC that is 6V high (126VAC) and you need 5A resistive you could use a 6V 5A transformer (a 30VA transformer) to buck the extra voltage. That can be compared to 126:120 transformer that would have to be 600VA so around 20 times heavier and larger.
While a wire that is in air in your home wiring does interact slightly with nearby changing magnetic fields, the effect is very small compared to the fields the wire itself creates when significant current is passing through it.
That's why we need to have a big heavy iron core and a lot of copper to make a decent mains-frequency transformer.

that 2nd circuit diagram and explanation was extremely helpful. thank you!

An autotransformer does indeed have a single winding, but that winding has three connection points - one at each end of the winding, and one somewhere in the middle.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
(consider the two coils as representing a single winding with a center connection)
This is a step-up autotransformer - apply 120 V between the bottom and center connections and you will get 240 V over the full winding (top to bottom).  The voltages will be proportional to the number of turns between connections, as in a normal transformer - the input and output sides share part of the single winding.
